# DB2 - What is the difference between online backup and AUTO_DB_BACKUP?

Tags: backup, db2

We would like to perform online backup.
I see that there is one parameter AUTO_DB_BACKUP.
I read this article on IBM link for AUTO_DB_BACKUP  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0801ganesan/

but still I cannot see the purpose of this AUTO_DB_BACKUP when online backup is ON.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AUTO_DB_BACKUP` means DB2 will take a backup [based on when it feels it should do so](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0011779.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-0-0-2-6&lang=en). The things that influence the taking of a backup are:

- Never completed a full backup
- Time elapsed since the last full backup was a specified number of hours
- Transaction log space consumed (with archival logging enabled), since the last full backup is a specified size.

In order to have `AUTO_DB_BACKUP` working, you also need to have `AUTO_MAINT` turned `ON` as well. I would also wager a guess that in order to enable the scheduling part, you may need to have the DBM CFG `HEALTH_MON` turned to `ON` as well.

Most DB2 DBAs I talk to turn off `HEALTH_MON` and `AUTO_MAINT` because of the performance issues encountered. DB2 may choose to exercise maintenance and backups when it is least convenient for you. So I would recommend against using them, unless you are using BLU under DB2 10.5. Then it sounds like `AUTO_MAINT` [may be more important again](http://db2commerce.com/2015/01/06/db2-basics-what-is-blu/).

Anyway, an online backup is just a backup while users are still engaging the database and/or the database is activated. You can take online or offline backups regardless of whether or not you have `AUTO_MAINT` and `AUTO_DB_BACKUP` enabled. You probably want online backups enabled if you wish to use `AUTO_DB_BACKUP` in case DB2 decides to take a backup in the middle of the day. Otherwise it could either fail to backup, or kick users off the system. I'm not sure which as I've never tried. Like I said, I steer clear of `HEALTH_MON` and `AUTO_MAINT`.

This way I can either take scripted backups when I want them scheduled via a job scheduler. Or I can take an on-demand online or offline depending on the situation.

Comment: Hi Chris OK thank you it also sounded to me that AUTO_DB_BACKUP is not necessary.

Comment: Chris can you please help me with issue on this link? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91807/online-backup-is-not-performed-from-the-cron-job-on-linux-server-manually-it-wo